# How to set up a orbiting camera with zoom in the BGE?

Tags: game-engine, camera

How can I zoom in and out using the mouse wheel in the BGE? And press the middle button to go move around the character?

I want the camera to be parent to the character so that it will follow it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this is by adding an empty at the point which you want the camera to orbit around, and adding a mouse look actuator to it:

[image]

Then parent the camera to it with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.

For zooming, you can do something like this on the camera:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: And how we can set how far the zoom stop?

Comment: This, for sure, isn't the only way. You can surely do it in Python.

Comment: @AdriansNetlis Yes.. And..? (the first sentence of my answer starts with "*one* way to do this..")

Comment: Sorry, my reading mistake. I read as if you had told "Only way to do this".;)