# How to pan my view around in a blender game?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

How can I pan my camera around in a blender game? I want to be able to use camera controls in my blender game Like panning 360 around with the right mouse button. My view does not need to pan up or down, just needs to rotate around the view like to say I have a cube to represent my character! I want to be able to pan the view around it.

Comment: if your going to mark this as a duplicate at least link me to other peoples questions asking this

Comment: At top. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17964/how-to-set-up-a-orbiting-camera-with-zoom-in-the-bge